# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 address=0x0 in XCode/ AVFoundation/ iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

XCode 8.0
Swift 4

I use AVFoundation/AVAudioRecorder and want to record something, but iOS simulator always crash.

referring to this code: [AVFoundation | gendelisa](https://github.com/genedelisa/AVFoundationRecorder/blob/master/AVFoundation%20Recorder/RecorderViewController.swift)

code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import NCMB

class RecordViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
    var recorder = AVAudioRecorder()
    let user = NCMBUser.current() //ログイン中のユーザーIDの取得
    var chapter = 1 //チャプター番号を取得

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

   //*********[...]************

    func recordSetting() {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        } catch {
            print("categorize failed")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        do {
            try session.setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("session activate failed")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        let soundFileName = "\(getToday())\(user?.userName! ?? "")-\(chapter!).m4a"
        let tempFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory()
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(tempFilePath)\(soundFileName)")
        print("write to \(fileURL)")
        let recordSetting: [String: Any] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.medium.rawValue,
            AVEncoderBitRateKey: 128,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0
        ]
        do {
            recorder = try AVAudioRecorder.init(url: fileURL, settings: recordSetting)  //error in this sentence
            recorder.delegate = self
            recorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
            recorder.prepareToRecord()
            print("setting succeeded")
        } catch {
            print("setting failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    //***********[...]************

    func getToday() {
    //get today's date and time
    }
}
```

the error ' `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` ' has occurred in phrase `recorder = try AVAudioRecorder.init(url: fileURL, settings: recordSetting)` .

error log in `0 -[AVAudioRecorder privCommonCleanup]`:

```
1 AVFAudio`-[AVAudioRecorder privCommonCleanup]:
~ //...
8   ->  0x118f15a08 <+18>:  movq   $0x0, (%rbx)  //error
```

searching for Internet, this error seems to occur because of unexpected memory releasing, I don't know much about this field and cannot solve this problem.

otherwise is it bug of iOS simulator or swift 4?

Answer (score -1):

sorry there is mistyped phrase in line 6 and done when correct it

false
`var recorder = AVAudioRecorder()`

true
    `var recorder: AVAudioRecorder!`

Comment: Do you mean you've fixed the issue by changing line 6 (just a typo) ? If so, I would recommend to delete your question/answer since not helpful for other people.